# How to make letter grow on type and shrink on backspace in input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to make an animated input field, such that every letter animates in/out on type/backspace. I imagine that I will have to wrap every letter with a span, like so:

```
<span class="animateLetter">A</span>
<span class="animateLetter">B</span>
<span class="animateLetter">C</span>
```

But then I lose the dynamic nature of the `<input>` tag.

The ultimate goal is

```
<input onChange=animateLetter />
```

Where animateLetter is a function that determines the letter just typed or deleted, and animates its addition or deletion.

Since you cannot wrap the letter values of the value property on the 'input' tag, let alone add a class to those spans, this becomes rather tricky.

Comment: you can use `onkeypress` or `onkeydown`. For complexe JavaScript, I recommend you not use inline javascript. You may want to use an invisible input where the user types, and animate the content on a separate div

Comment: @Ibu I was thinking of something similar to the invisible typing layer, but then how could the user use the cursor to select and delete the text? I think that might be more of a hack than a long term solution

Comment: You could create and substitute an element with styles set to `<input>` element to render element displayed as `<input>` element within `document`; use `<span>` elements, `css` as described at Question to animate text input

Comment: This would be a typical use case for [Web Components](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements) - unfortunately, browser support, especially for the [Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom) is not yet what it should be.

Comment: That animate on backspace sounds REALLY annoying to end user ... Just a thought.  I'd let that go

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You know, you can make it like how element in gmail work. in gmail. each time you add people to recipient, it add one div besides of the text area. so in your problem, whenever javascript detect change in input, you add an element (span or div) right before the input text. You can mask it like the one I do below.just remember that, everytime onchange fired, you need to delete the text in  add  or  text before the input. I don't really have time to implement the script to add text and the animation. for animation, you can take it from https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. it has many great animation that you can use.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}

.wrapper .letter {
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input {
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="letter">h</div>
  <div class="letter">e</div>
  <div class="letter">l</div>
  <div class="letter">l</div>
  <div class="letter">o</div>
  <input onchange='addTextAnimation()'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Remember that in this solution, user can't block the text and delete it. they must use backspace to delete the text one by one. and again, this need javascript too.